# Microsoft optimizing compiler 8.00 linker issue

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

```
#include<stdio.h>

void CopyBuffer(char *dest, char *src, int len)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, len);
}

    int main()
    {
        char *text = "Hello";
        char buf[20];
        CopyBuffer(buf, text, 6);
    }
```

While using MSVC to compile above code I am facing couple of linking error saying

> unresolved external

One example is if I use memcpy it is throwing error message

> error L2029: '_memcpy' : unresolved external  error L2029:
>   '__acrtused' : unresolved external  error L2029: '__aNchkstk' :
>   unresolved external

Do I need to add library path during linking. But I have also observed if I use maximum optimization using /Ox _memcpy and __aNchkstk don't appear. Linker version is as it appear in console

> Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5
>   1994

Comment: `memcpy` lives in `<string.h>`

Comment: I added string.h and also specified the path the INCLUDE folder with /I and still it says _memcpy unresolved external, also I am getting this error during linking.

Comment: This all seems strange, like the CRT isn't getting linked. Could you add your complete command line (compile & link if you do it in two steps) to your post? (I don't use VC, so can't really help, sorry.)

Comment: Have you raised by any chance the 'ignore default library' flag?